# Starting ActiveMQ with Stomp

Tags: java, xml, activemq-classic

I am facing the error given in below stack trace, When starting activemq with this command  **"activemq start xbean:../conf/activemq-stomp.xml"**

> E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.4.3\bin>**activemq
>   start xbean:../conf/activemq-stomp.xml** Java Runtime: Oracle
>   Corporation 1.7.0_51 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre   Heap
>   sizes: current=61440k  free=59137k  max=465920k
>       JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xmx512M -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dactivemq.classpath=E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.4.3/conf;E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.4.3/conf;
>   -Dactivemq.home=E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-a ACTIVEMQ_HOME: E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.4.3 ACTIVEMQ_BASE:
>   E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.4.3 Loading message
>   broker from: start ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to
>   execute start task. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Invalid broker URI, no scheme specified: start
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid broker URI, no scheme
>   specified: start
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:98)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:143)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:85)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:251)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:107) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid broker URI, no scheme
>   specified: start
>           at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:68)
>           at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:91)
>           ... 10 more ERROR: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid broker URI, no scheme
>   specified: start java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid broker URI, no scheme
>   specified: start
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:99)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:143)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:85)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:251)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:107) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid broker URI, no scheme
>   specified: start
>           at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:68)
>           at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
>           at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:91)
>           ... 10 more E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.4.3\bin>

ActiveMQ is starting properly with command

E:\apache-activemq-5.4.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.4.3\bin>**activemq**
Its starting properly i am able to view the ActiveMQ console at **http://localhost:8161/admin/**

I want to use the stomp protocol and want start with command **activemq start xbean:conf/activemq-stomp.xml**

Please reply to my query. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

hey You do not need to do `activemq start` as 'start' is implicit

just do `activemq`

The problem is that the 'start' string is being interpreted as the broker URL.

hope this helps!
Good luck

Comment: @SyedAtiqurRahman have a look here http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html , if you have missed some steps , this will help you in setting it up

Comment: giving activemq 
It works, I can view the web console. 

activemq.xml is currently have this as  default transport Connector 
 <transportConnectors>
      <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
</transportConnectors>

To use stomp protocol do i need to add this lines in activemq.xml or should I use activemq-stomp.xml instead
<transportConnectors>
     <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61612?transport.closeAsync=false"/> 
  <transportConnector name="stomp+nio" uri="stomp+nio:/0.0.0.0:61613?transport.closeAsync=false"/> 
</transportConnectors>

Comment: yes you need to add the lines you mentioned for using stomp, as stmp protocol will be activated on these ports once you run activeMQ

Comment: Thanks Vihar !!...

I have added the transportConnectors tag in activemq.xml
<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61612?transport.closeAsync=false"/>

now i am able to view the queue on ActiveMQ web console.